# How to disable global table writing permission?

Tags: android, android-developer-api

I turned on global table permission by using this code ( pm grant by4a.setedit22  android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
) via ladb for setedit. now i want to turn off, and what's the code for turning off?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.